# No pagebreak between citation entries in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

currently iam formatting my bibliography. If an entry cannot be placed on the end of a page without a pagebreak (the citation would be splitted on two pages) latex automatically induces a pagebreak. I thik, it looks a bit weird if the pages are not used to an equal extent.

Though some solutions are visible in google, I would like to ask if you know a very simple way to change it , i.e. use the full page and split entries to two pages.

Kind regards,

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Identation after chapter header
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/} }
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},
        %belowskip=-10pt,
           %aboveskip=0pt
        singlelinecheck=false
       ]{caption}                           
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=none,isbn=false,eprint=false,
doi=false,style=ieee,dashed=false,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % List of symbols
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section} % Spacing before/after (sub-) section titles
{0pt}{16pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{18pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{. }}{0pt} 
{\Huge\bfseries} % Title without "Chapter" but Nr. in front

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package


\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package


\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
%\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
%\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
 }
 }



\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
top=1.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
headheight=15pt 
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\setlength{\headsep}{0.4 cm} % Spacing between header and textblock below
\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}
%\geometry{headheight=29.54742pt}
%\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}

%\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5 cm}
```

Comment: I think setting the option \raggedbottom in the document causes Latex to not try so hard to make nice paragraphs. I use this in my documents to get even space between paragraphs, which otherwise tend to be stretched to fit if the last paragraph is moved over to next page and not just split. Maybe it would work for your problem too, I haven't checked my bibliography for this effect specifically.

Comment: @Plergux Unfortunately, it does not work for me.

Comment: Even \flushbottom does not stretch the content over a whole page. How can I do that ...

Comment: Would adjusting the bibitemsep not be easier on the eye?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, breaks *are* allowed in bibitems, but not between the first and second line, and they are discouraged before the final line. So a two-line bibitem will not break. You can insert the settings

```
\clubpenalty=0 \widowpenalty=0
```

to allow those breaks without penalty. If some package prevents *all* linebreaks, add `\interlinepenalty=0` to the two above.

If you use an explicit `thebibliography` environment, it is easy to insert the settings, but it is more difficult for `\bibliography` or `\printbibliography`. The cleanest way would be using the facilities of some package (for example, natbib has `\@bibsetup`), but here is an ugly hackish way

```
\let\prevTheBib\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{\prevTheBib{#1}%
   \clubpenalty=0 \widowpenalty=0\relax}
```

If the package is biblatex, it should be enough to change `\bibsetup` (which is a macro, not a declaration hook as I thought). The (or a) normal `\bibsetup` is

```
\bibsetup ->\interlinepenalty =5000\relax \widowpenalty =10000\relax
  \clubpenalty =10000\relax \raggedbottom \frenchspacing \biburlsetup
```

which gives *ALL* your problems! Both preventing breaks and making the bottom ragged.  So change it:

```
\renewcommand\bibsetup{\clubpenalty=0 \widowpenalty=0 \interlinepenalty=0 
      \flushbottom \frenchspacing \biburlsetup}
```

Finally, after comments, you want flush bottom but set a rigid `\bibitemsep`, leaving no flexibility in the vertical list. On whatever page looks ragged-bottom, you should get a warning about

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

meaning the page isn't intentionally ragged, but another line of text can't fit on it, and the text can't adjust position. Try a setting of

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.75\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

instead. The default `\bibitemsep` of 0pt is more problematic, but you could try

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{0pt plus 0.1pt}
```

Achieving flush bottoms without any flexibility falls into the realm of "typesetting on a grid", and everything on the page has to be carefully crafted to occupy a multiple of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Is that not the exact opposite? That is to say, the high number of \interlinepenalty basically says not to break the entries (paragraphs) ever? If he wants to break the paragraphs would it not be better to use a low number (i.e. lower penalty)?

Comment: Yeah, it does not work guys. I just want to have the content of a page in the bibliography to be stretched to a maximum so that I use the complete page foreseen, without blank lines at the bottom.

Comment: @Ptergux that's how I read the question.

Comment: Sorry about the reverse answer. Replaced now.

Comment: No problem, but it does not work. I try to play with the Bibitem seperation ... I want the last word to be at the lowest position possible in my document.

Comment: It sounds like you have `\raggedbottom` in your document. Declare `\flushbottom` instead.

Comment: How "not work"? It should allow breaks, but some detail in your specific document might be interfering. It does nothing to change a `\raggedbottom` setting.

Comment: You can see relevant preamble codes now, please check it. I also guess, another setting prevents the /flushbottom to be applied. Thanks for your time.

Comment: \addbibresource is in. I load chapters in via /input. This is the code part for the Bibliography in the main document:                                                           
    \chapter*{Bibliography}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\singlespacing
    \raggedright
    \flushbottom
    %\interlinepenalty=10000
    \setlength\bibitemsep{0.75\baselineskip}

\printbibliography

Comment: Sorry I missed \bibresource. I added a suggestion for `\bibsetup`

Comment: I dont know why, but nothing works.

Comment: I think I found.

Comment: Man it still not works. I really want to thank you for your great efforts. I do not want to bother anyone anymore with its costful time. Thanks for your help, I will have to see what I do then.

Comment: Still I have that problem, nothing works. Im going crazy soon ... I dont know why this all does not work... What is if I work in the .bbl file with txt editor as I already did. I have read I can prevent pagebreaks there.

Comment: The .bbl file was created with Citavi and I have modified the entries sometimes with the text editor.

Comment: Oh my god!!! Now, i deleted the chapter from bibliography, and just did \printbibliography. However, every commands Ive performed AFTER that command, that means it cannot be affected. Now, the problem is finally cleared, it works!